# Maximum flow algorithm : excess calculus

Tags: algorithms

In an exercice I have to calculate the excess of a, b, c.

[image: Graph]

I found e(a) = 0, e(b) = 2, e(c) = 4 but seems false referring to a correction.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank's

Comment: Isn't the excess of $c$ $6$? And $1$ for $a$? Or am I looking at the wrong quantity?

Comment: @Arthur if so, it mean that _t_ (the end) can send back ? In this case, e(a) = 1, e(b) = 2, e(c) = 6 ?